# Can java do printIn in Android?

Tags: java, android, button, println

I have an EditText, and when a button is clicked, I want the text to be displayed on the screen. And the EditText can be used again to add other text and on and on. Thanks!

Something like:

[image]

Comment: Post some code or give more information so we can help you more.

Comment: System.getProperty("line.separator");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code for that, it will solve your problem.

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findviewById(R.id.editText1);
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findviewById(R.id.textView1);
plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        textView1.append("\n"+editText1.getText().toString());
                         // OR
        textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString()+"\n"+editText1.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm searching it for quite sometime. TQ

Comment: I wanna ask, if I clicked in the plusBtn, and the code behind add the value in the textView1 into the database, can this be done?

Comment: @milktea yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
  EditText et = (EditText)findviewById(R.id.et1);
  TextView display = (TextView)findviewById(R.id.tv1);
  plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            tv1.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"\n"+et.getText().toString());
             //prints the text from edittext and concatinates it to the textview previous text
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Views to your Layout by using its addView() Method. So you could add a TextView upon each button-click which contains the content of your TextField.